# AngularJS: Information does not appear in {{}}

Tags: angularjs

I'm brand new at AngularJS, watching a Lynda.com video series on it, "Up and Running with AngularJS with Ray Villalobos." I can't get past this error notice. I'm using WAMP to display an external Ajax file data.json with an $http service.

I don't understand why my content is not displaying on the screen. All that shows onscreen is the CSS border for the div and the "Photo of" alt text. Nothing in the {{}}'s display. ONce I started using the WAMP server, the content stopped appearing - the server is started, though. Here is the error:

```
"http://localhost/AngularJS/lib/angular/angular.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one"
GET http://localhost/AngularJS/images/.jpg
```

Also, there should be a list of only 4 items, but I'm getting a much longer list than that.

**My controllers.js:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { 
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.cars = data;
    });
}]);
```

**My html:**

```
<div ng-controller = "MyController">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in cars track by $index">
    <div class="section">
        <h2>{{item.model}}</h2>
        <img ng-src="images/{{item.shortname}}.jpg" width="200px" alt="Photo of {{item.model}}" title="Photo of {{item.model}}">
        <h3>{{item.description}}</h3>
        <p>{{item.edition + ', ' + item.bodytype}}</p>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This cuts the listing to only 4, but the {{}} content still does not show: <li ng-repeat="item in cars | limitTo: 4">

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the data.json file. It began with **var myApp =**. Once I removed that, it worked.